# violin plot in python function and plotly

Tags: python, function, plotly, violin-plot

I have created a python function to draw a violin plot using plotly. The code for that is:

```
    def print_violin_plot(data1,data2,type1,type2,fig_title):
        data = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Group', 'Number'))
        for i in data1:
            x = pd.DataFrame({'Group' : [type1],
                      'Number' : [i],})
        data = data.append(x, ignore_index=True) 
        for i in data2:
            x = pd.DataFrame({'Group' : [type2],
                      'Number' : [i],})
        data = data.append(x, ignore_index=True)  

       fig = FF.create_violin(data, data_header='Number',     
       group_header='Group', height=500, width=800, title= fig_title)
       py.iplot(fig, filename="fig_title")
```

I then call the function

```
    print_violin_plot(eng_t['grade'],noneng_t['grade'],'English 
    Speaking','Non-English Speaking', 'Grades')
```

The function runs fine, without any errors, but I dont see any output. Why?

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over `data1` and `data2` you assign new instances of `pd.DataFrame` to the variable `x` and with each iteration you overwrite the `x`. If you want to append the instances of `pd.DataFrame` you should move the data.append(x) to the for-loop. Also, `data.append()` returns None, it's a method working on the `data` object, so `data = data.append(..)` results in `data == None`. Your code should look like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Group', 'Number'))
for i in data1:
        x = pd.DataFrame({'Group' : [type1],
                  'Number' : [i],})
for i in data2:
        x = pd.DataFrame({'Group' : [type2],
                  'Number' : [i],})
        data.append(x, ignore_index=True)
```

To be clear, I must say that I have no idea what `pg.DataFrame` means or does, but what I wrote above is for sure a flaw in your code. I assumed that `pg.DataFrame` instances support `append` method and work just like `lists`.